# Reading haven created dta file in Stata - how to deal with dots in variable names?

Tags: r, stata, r-haven, dta

We are working in Stata with data created in R, that have been exported using `haven` package. We stumbled upon an issue with variables that have a dot in the name. To replicate the problem, some minimal R code:

```
library("haven")
var.1 <- c(1,2,3)
var_2 <- c(1,2,3)
test_df <- employ.data <- data.frame(var.1, var_2)
str(test_df)
write_dta(test_df, "D:/test_df.dta")
```

Now, in Stata, when I do:

```
use "D:\test_df.dta"
d
```

First problem - I get an empty dataset. Second problem - we get variable name with a dot - which in Stata should be illegal. Therefore any command using directly the variable name like

```
drop var.1
```

returns an error:

```
factor variables and time-series operators not allowed
r(101);
```

What is causing such behaviour? Any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

This will `drop var.1` in Stata:

```
drop var?1
```

Here (as in Excel), `?` is used as a wildcard for a single character. (The regular expression equivalent to `.`)

Unfortunately, this will also `drop var_1`, if it exists.

I am not sure about the missing values when writing a .dta file with `haven`. I am able to replicate this result in Stata 14.1 and `haven` 0.2.0.
However, using the `read_dta` function from `haven`,

```
temp2 <- read_dta("test_df.dta")
```

returns the data.frame. As an alternative to `haven`, I have used the `readstata13` package in the past without issues.

```
library(readstata13)
save.dta13(test_df, "testdf.dta")
```

While this code has the same variable names issue, it provided a .dta file that contained the correct values when read into Stata 14.1. There is a convert.underscore argument to `save.dta13`, that is intended to remove non-valid characters in Stata variable names. I verified that it will work properly in this example for `readstata13` for version 0.8.5, but had a bug in some earlier versions including version 0.8.2.

Comment: Thanks Imo. `drop` trick is indeed a good one, at least for this particular example. Can also confirm that `readstata13` creates dataset readable in Stata.